# C++ automated scoring system

Tags: c++, sorting

I am having trouble completing an assignment according to specifications.  Here is the assignment scenario:

> A college is in desperate need of an automated test scoring system. Using C++, write a scoring system for the college and score the tests of at least five students.
>
> To create the scoring system, follow the steps below:
>
> First ask for the number of questions in the test
>
> Then asks for the correct answers for each question. Note that multiple choice tests and questions will have answers from A to D.
>
> Ask for the number of students and process each student by asking for their name and then loop through the questions asking for the student's answer.
>
> Score each question.
>
> After the last question calculate the students score and display "Student 'insert student name' scored 10 out of 20 or 50%."
>
> Repeat until all the students have been scored.
>
> After all students are scored, insert a print a class list of all the student's results in the same manner as before.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //declare variables
    char choice;
    string studentName;
    vector<char> answers;
    vector<string> names;
    int getStudents();
    int getQuestions();
    
    //calls function to get number of questions
    float questions = getQuestions();


    //Get answers
    for (int i = 0; i < questions; ++i) {
        cout << "What is the answer for question " << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        answers.push_back(choice);
    }

    //Get number of students
    int students = getStudents();


    //Get student names
    for (int i = 0; i < students; i++) {
        cout << "Student " << i + 1 << ", what is your name?" << endl;
        cin >> studentName;
        names.push_back(studentName);
    }

    float score = 0;
    char studentAnswer;
    vector<char> userAnswer;
    vector<float> finalScore;
        
    //gets student answers
    for (int i = 0; i < students; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < questions; j++) {
            cout << names[i] << ", what is your answer for question " << j + 1 << "?" << endl;
            cin >> studentAnswer;
            userAnswer.push_back(studentAnswer);
        }
    }

    

    //calculates student scores
    for (int i = 0; i < students; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < questions; j++) {
            if (userAnswer[j] == answers[j])
                score = score + 1;
                }       
        finalScore.push_back(score);
    }

    //outputs scores
    for (int i = 0; i < students; i++) {
        cout << names[i] << " scored " << finalScore[i] << " out of " << questions <<
            " or " << (finalScore[i] / questions) * 100 << "%" << endl;
    }

    

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
//function to get number of questions
int getQuestions()
{
    int questions;
    cout << "How many questions are there?" << endl;
    cin >> questions;
    return questions;
}
//function to get number of students
int getStudents()
{
    int students;
    cout << "How many students are there?" << endl;
    cin >> students;
    return students;
}
```

The values returned for final score are not accurate and I can not find where the error is occurring.

Also for the sorting in the last step, I have been asked to sort as a combination of the scores in descending order and names in ascending or alphabetical order.  I am able to sort these independently of each other but not sure how to combine them and sort them that way.

Comment: About the sorting, you should in any case show what you have got so far, but it would probably be better to open a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//calculates student scores
for (int i = 0; i < students; i++) {
    score = 0; //Fabio was right you need to reset score to 0 for each student
    for (int j = 0; j < questions; j++) {
        if (userAnswer[j] == answers[j])
            score = score + 1;
            }       
    finalScore.push_back(score);
}
```

When you check to see if `userAnswer` is equal to `answers` you always start back at 0. So you are checking student 1's answers every time. You could try:

```
if (userAnswer[i*questions+j] == answers[j])
```

Comment: Nice catch, I had missed it.

Comment: Thank you kyho, this has solved my calculation problems but I do not completely understand the logic for the changes to the if statement.  Could you please clarify this for me?  The way I read it the outside loop increments for each new student and the inside loop should check the answers beginning from the first question.

Comment: userAnswer.push_back(studentAnswer) pushes all students' answers onto the same vector. So if you have 3 students and there are 3 questions, the vector could be something like: {A,B,C,C,B,B,A,B,A}. In your if statement you were looking at the first 3 answers each time, userAnswer[0], userAnswer[1], userAnswer[2]. In this case multiplying j with i*question gives you 0,1,2 for the first student, 3,4,5 for the second, and 6,7,8 for the third. This way you are getting the correct values in your userAnswer vector for each student.

Answer (score 3):

You initialize `score` to 0, but then you don't reset it for every student. You should do this:

```
    //calculates student scores
    for (int i = 0; i < students; i++) {
        score = 0; // here, so that it is reset for each student
```

By the way, your `questions` variable is a `float`, I think you want an `int`.

Comment: I had made the questions variable a float for purpose of calculating a percent at the end.  Is that not necessary?

Comment: @RyanA no, you can keep it an `int` (which is its real type) and, if you want, use `static_cast<float>(score)` when evaluating the formula. But actually in this case you don't need it, as `finalscore[i]` is already a `float`, so `questions` is automatically cast to `float` and the result is also a `float`.